# Shiny Server and R: How can I start the download of a file through the URL?

Tags: linux, r, wget, shiny-server

I want to use the linux `wget` command on several URLs.  In Shiny, right clicking the download button or link gives the following info:

`../session/../download/downloadData?w=`

This can be used with the linux wget command to download the file if the page is open.

Is it possible to begin a Shiny download using the URL link without knowing the session data?

My goal is to do something like this:

```
wget "http://home:3838/../#apples=3" -O /home/../apples.csv

wget "http://home:3838/../#pears=3" -O /home/../pears.csv
```

and so on.

I already know how to add parameters but I do not know how to actuate the download.

Comment: I have been working to find an answer for a while. If you found one please share. I'll be back if I can find it

Answer (score 0):

If the author implemented their download button using [downloadHandler](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.3/downloadhandler) and  [downloadLink/downloadButton](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.3/downloadbutton), what you described should work.

I.e., first, get the download link (right-click and copy the link address), and then run wget as:

```
wget <download-link> -O <target_file_name>
```